# My mac air 2015 wont work with two exteranl mointeres

Tags: macbook-pro

why is my 2015 MacBook air make my two external monitors mirror and the second one won't come up on the arrangement pls help!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Apparently, your model of MacBook Air supports only a single external display.